# LunarVim not recognizing Haskell Language Server in Nix-environment

Tags: nix, lunarvim, haskell-language-server

I have a nix working environment (created by my colleague - I have no nix skills myself) for programming in Haskell, and I am using LunarVim as the editor. It is set up on my desktop and my laptop.
The setups are close to identical:
Both computers have AMD Ryzen processors are running on LinuxMint 21.  The only clear hardware difference is that the desktop has an AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT graphics card whereas the Laptop's GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile.
The environment has been git-cloned from a git repository. LunarVim is setup close to identically on both computers and :checkhealth gives very similar output.

On the desktop, it works fine, but on the laptop, I get the error message "Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0 a short while after starting LunarVim. The Language Server status remains at 'LSP inactive'.

In the lsp-log, the following catches the eye:

```
$HOME/.local/share/lvim/mason/packages/haskell-language-server/lib/haskell-language-server-2.4.0.0/bin//haskell-language-server-9.2.8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_ABI_DT_RELR' not found (required by /nix/store/x33pcmpsiimxhip52mwxbb5y77dhmb21-glibc-2.37-8/lib/librt.so.1)
```

Is this the root of the problem? If yes, how to solve it? If not, how should I continue to troubleshoot?

Comment: This is very likely the root of the problem. I’m not an expert on this, but I suspect that somehow multiple versions of `libc.so.6` are used at once, not sure why (driver? improper os configuration?). What is surpring is that usually the error is in the other way: `/nix/…/lib/…: version XX not found (required by /lib/…)`, because the library in `/lib/` is the driver provided by the system, and is linked with a too recent glibc than the one provided by the software (i.e. you might run into problem when using old softwares on recent systems if you use drivers/opengl/…).

Comment: But in your case, you are using the `glibc` of the system, I’m not sure why, and the library (in nix) seems to ask for a more recent version.  Can you first check if you have not set `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set? Maybe post here the result of `env | grep LD_`. Then, maybe try to run `export LD_PRELOAD=/nix/store/x33pcmpsiimxhip52mwxbb5y77dhmb21-glibc-2.37-8/lib/libc.so.6` before running your program. Related discussions might be https://discourse.nixos.org/t/could-we-robustly-protect-against-errors-version-glibc-2-33/18343

Comment: Also, note that you will certainly get more help from discourse.nixos.org/, or possibly the matrix chat.

Comment: @tobiasBora ; Thank you for your reply, here are the outputs:

`$ export LD_PRELOAD=/nix/store/x33pcmpsiimxhip52mwxbb5y77dhmb21-glibc-2.37-8/lib/libc.so.6`
`$ lvim Auth.hs `
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

`$ env | grep LD`_
**NIX_BUILD_CORES=12**
**NIX_BUILD_TOP=/build**

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem turned out to be a conflict between the Nix environment and Mason. If Mason doesn't provide a HLS, then LunarVim
correctly uses the one provided by Nix.

However, Mason is overly eager on installing its own HLS environment
even after I uninstall it. The only solution I've found is nukeing
any HLS:s Mason has:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/lvim/mason/packages/haskell-language-server
```

(needless to say - be careful with this!)